# Can't reach internet from subnet

Tags: networking, routing, cisco, linux-networking

I have setup a router which has dd-wrt on it which I have connected to my cisco switch. The current configuration is 192.168.1.0/24 if the subnet for the router and devices connected to it. 192.168.2.0/24 is the subnet used to link the router and the 10.0.0.0/24 subnet that is on my switch.

From the switch I can reach any ip in my LAN including 192.168.1.1 and any host on my network can reach 10.0.0.0 after adding the following rule in my routers routing table...

```
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.1
```

However from the 10.0.0.1 interface on my switch I can't reach 8.8.8.8 however I can from 192.168.2.2 on the switch.

Here is the entire routing table on the router

```
default via [redacted] dev eth0 
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.1 
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  scope link 
169.254.0.0/16 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 169.254.255.1 
173.75.31.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 173.75.31.25 
192.168.1.0/24 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1 
192.168.2.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.1
```

here is the iptables rules on the router.

```
root@DD-WRT:~# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp spt:bootps dpt:bootpc 
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:route 
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:route 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:route 
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     igmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:auth 
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW 
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW 
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       0    --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     gre  --  192.168.1.0/24       anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.1.0/24       anywhere            tcp dpt:1723 
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             anywhere            
lan2wan    0    --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             base-address.mcast.net/4 
TRIGGER    0    --  anywhere             anywhere            TRIGGER type:in match:0 relate:0 
trigger_out  0    --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW 
DROP       0    --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             anywhere
```

ifconfig

```
ath0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 60:38:E0:DB:AD:B3  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4013297 errors:0 dropped:419 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5881012 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:291261174 (277.7 MiB)  TX bytes:8927857512 (8.3 GiB)

ath1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 60:38:E0:DB:AD:B4  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3681 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:515104 (503.0 KiB)

br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 60:38:E0:DB:AD:B2  
          inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4010466 errors:0 dropped:1293 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5874845 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:234596315 (223.7 MiB)  TX bytes:8809281468 (8.2 GiB)

br0:0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 60:38:E0:DB:AD:B2  
          inet addr:169.254.255.1  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 60:38:E0:DB:AD:B2  
          inet addr:redacted  Bcast:redacted  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5874872 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4005880 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8809323335 (8.2 GiB)  TX bytes:290200222 (276.7 MiB)
          Interrupt:194 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 60:38:E0:DB:AD:B2  
          inet addr:192.168.2.1  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:532 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:168 (168.0 B)
          Interrupt:195 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:452 (452.0 B)  TX bytes:452 (452.0 B)
```

Comment: Please, show ifconfig.

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy added ifconfig

Comment: @mschuett, what is the gateway ip of 10.0.0.0/24 network?

Comment: 10.0.0.1 is the gateway for computers on that network

Comment: @mschuett, where have you configured it? pls see if you can reach that from a host.

Comment: I can ping that gateway from all hosts on my local network. for instance i'm on my computer with ip 192.168.1.42 and gateway 192.168.1.1 and can ping it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to properly set up nat translation on the edge router...

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to 173.75.6.2
```

After running this I was able to ping the internet from 10.0.0.0/24. For other people who run into this issue you can issue the command below to see what your current nat configuration looks like.

```
iptables -t nat -L
```